# Опциональное сочетание клавиш в браузерах

Tags: javascript, pure_js

Вопрос к js скриптерам. Как игнорировать опциональное сочетание клавиш в браузерах и назначить свои действия? Данная возможность реализована на ХэшКоде, **ctrl+b**, *ctrl+i*, ctrl+l и т.д!

Подкиньте мыслей в какую сторону крутить скрипт, **желательно** на нативном js!

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: З.Ы. Только вот в комментировании эти сочетания не работают)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65){ //ctrl+a
        if(window.getSelection){
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
        }
        console.log('Weee!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Вот только что делать с FF, я пока не придумал - все равно выделяет все на странице, хотя и сообщение выдает.

**Обновлено**
Походу, в FF нет стандартного способа обхода всех действий по умолчанию, поэтому для каждой кнопки придется выкручиваться подобным способом.

Comment: А чем это отличается от того, что выше?

Comment: да вот с FF тоже гемороюсь...

Comment: @Asen return false; есть XD))) Тут реально с FF проблема!

Comment: Пока печатал, вы меня обогнали).  
Отличия - в отсутствии инлайнового js и подавлении стандартного действия.

Comment: @knes привнес в вопрос новую метку `**pure_js**` пойду по гуглю пошляюсь)))

Comment: Да, и правда, в лисе ничего не работает... Складывается такое ощущение, что там вообще нет объекта "event".

Comment: @ling ништяк... сшил всё что нужно было во едино, РАБОТАЕТ! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот, как создать горячую клавишу (CTRL+A), этот код можно адаптировать для запрета на выделение всего текста на странице сайта. Как запрограммировать другие хоткеи, должно быть понятно. **Код кроссбраужерный, на нативном JS =)**

```
function ctrlA(event)
    {
        var event = event || window.event;
        var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
if(event.ctrlKey && key == 'A'.charCodeAt(0)) alert("CTRL+A !");
        }
```

**UPD:**
Вообщем, все дело в том, что в FF код нажатой клавиши читается в нижнем регистре, а не в верхнем...у каждого браузера свои заморочки, кроме того, в обработчик события надо передавать event:

```
<body onkeypress="f(event)">
<script>
function f(event)
{   
    var event=event || window.event;
        var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
if(event.ctrlKey && key == 'q'.charCodeAt(0)) alert("CTRL+A !");
if(event.ctrlKey==true && key == 1081) alert("CTRL+A !");
    }
</script>
```

А привинтить функцию можно, например, **к обработчику "onkeydown"** элемента body:

> `<body onkeydown="ctrlA()">`

Comment: Я уже перезацарапал такой подход, баян!

Comment: Чаго ?  +)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // игнорируем действие браузера
    // выполняем необходимые вам действия

    alert('тест');
});
```

[Пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/bufPj/)

Comment: Если бы меня интересовал Jquery я вопрос не задавал бы!

Answer (score 0):

```
body.onkeydown = function (e) {
      if (e.ctrlKey  && e.keyCode == 83 ) {
        ......
    }
    **e.preventDefault();**
};
```

Действие Ctrl+S отменено.